# Java Regular Expression to fetch particular String from a line of sentence in a file

Tags: java, regex

I need to read a file and fetch only the file names ending with .csv. the file will contain several lines like this below

```
-dataFileName ABC.csv -command ii
-dataFileName EFG.csv -command ii
-dataFileName HIJ.csv -command ii
-dataFileName MNPQR.csv -command ii
-dataFileName UVXYZ.csv -command ii
```

We can see that the **-dataFileName** [ XXXX ] **-command ii** is kind of repetitive

I want *ABC*.csv , *EFG*.csv , *HIJ*.csv ,*MNPQR*.csv ,*UVXYZ*.csv ,as my console output.

Comment: Please remove the "read a file part", it does not matter to your question.

Comment: This is a perfect opportunity to google about regex and learn them.

Comment: Please be more specific what it is exactly, what you need. Does the csv file name contain whitespace, are there quotes, are there variations, what characters can the file name contain.

Comment: Please tell us, what you tried and where you had problems.

Comment: Keeping it simple: You can use `-dataFileName (.*\\.csv) -command ii` and capture group 1

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann sorry i think i wasnt clear on explaining the requirement , Actually there is a .ctl file which contains above list of lines and there are around 2000+ lines and i just needed the file names ending with .csv , i thought of using the regular expression,

I used this suggested solution to fetch file names 
-dataFileName (.*\\.csv) -command ii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to leverage the repetition of -dataFileName and -command ii in your strings then you can simple do this in Java,

```
replaceAll("-dataFileName| -command ii", "")
```

and write code something like this,

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
            "-dataFileName ABC.csv -command ii",
            "-dataFileName EFG.csv -command ii",
            "-dataFileName HIJ.csv -command ii",
            "-dataFileName MNPQR.csv -command ii",
            "-dataFileName UVXYZ.csv -command ii"
    );

    list.forEach(x -> {System.out.println(x + " --> " + x.replaceAll("-dataFileName| -command ii", ""));});
}
```

This gives following output,

```
-dataFileName ABC.csv -command ii -->  ABC.csv
-dataFileName EFG.csv -command ii -->  EFG.csv
-dataFileName HIJ.csv -command ii -->  HIJ.csv
-dataFileName MNPQR.csv -command ii -->  MNPQR.csv
-dataFileName UVXYZ.csv -command ii -->  UVXYZ.csv
```

If you don't like that, you can use this simple regex to do the job,

```
-dataFileName (.*?) -command ii
```

and capture group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQM3NN/1)

Comment: why replace? At that point, you might as well just use substring(14, length-12)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you want to use a regex for this. You can easily write a simple parser for it that won't cause problem when your requirements change (need to handle quotes? easy enough with a parser, messy with a regex).

An example program that would do this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Scratch {

    private static final String INPUT = "-dataFileName ABC.csv -command ii\n" +
        "-dataFileName EFG.csv -command ii -dataFileName OAZE.csv\n" +
        "-dataFileName HIJ.csv -command ii\n" +
        "-dataFileName MNPQR.csv -command ii\n" +
        "-dataFileName UVXYZ.csv -command ii";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(INPUT))) {
            reader.lines()
                .flatMap(line -> fetchFilenamesFromArgumentLine(line, "dataFileName", "csv"))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }

    public static Stream<String> fetchFilenamesFromArgumentLine(String line, String argumentName, String extension) {
        Stream.Builder<String> resultBuilder = Stream.builder();

        int index = 0;
        String actualArgumentName = "-" + argumentName + " ";

        while ((index = line.indexOf(actualArgumentName, index)) >= 0) {
            int start = index + actualArgumentName.length();
            int end = line.indexOf(extension, start) + extension.length();

            resultBuilder.add(line.substring(start, end));
            index = end;
        }
        return resultBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , i actually have around 1900 plus lines and wanted to filter it out and down the line its expected the number of lines might increase so thought regex would help me. Yes you were right with using a simple parser than regex of small use case.